# Как убрать лишние символы?

Tags: python

```
<img alt="Lightshot screenshot" class="no-click screenshot-image" crossorigin="anonymous" id="screenshot-image" image-id="saawq4" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NR-6f8psQUWSechxExKg7g.png"/>
```

Как убрать лишние символы, но оставить только ссылку. Желательно код на python

Comment: Какие лишние символы вы хотите убрать и что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Все, но чтобы осталась ссылка на сайт

Comment: `print('<img alt="Lightshot screenshot" class="no-click screenshot-image" crossorigin="anonymous" id="screenshot-image" image-id="saawq4" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NR-6f8psQUWSechxExKg7g.png"/>'.split('"')[-2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так вас устроит?

```
import re

text = '<img alt="Lightshot screenshot" class="no-click screenshot-image" crossorigin="anonymous" id="screenshot-image" image-id="saawq4" src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/NR-6f8psQUWSechxExKg7g.png"/>'

match = re.search(r'src=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```